# Как загнать две переменные $_SESSION?

Tags: php

Ну вот например:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Это у нас выводит Логин юзера.
А как вывести еще к логину и его настоящее имя? (Оно указано при регистрации)

Спасибо заранее.

И чтоб было вот так на его странице:

> Добро пожаловать "Имя", Вы вошли в
> систему под логином "Логин"

Comment: Не так надо:<br><br>
<i>Кому</i> загнать две переменные? Трубы горят!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    $_SESSION['realname']
```

Не перепутай. Ключ массива должен быть обязательно realname. Иначе ничего не сработает. *trollface*

Юзэйдж:

```
$sql = 'select `realname`,`username`,`sex` from `users` where `username`='.$username.' and `password`='.md5($password);
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==1){
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
  $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
  $_SESSION['realname'] = $row->realname;
  switch($row->sex){
    case 0:
      $ending = "ая"; break;
    case 1: 
      $ending = "ая"; break;
    case 2: 
      $ending = "ое"; break;
    case 3:
      $ending = "ые"; break;
    default: 
      $ending = "... само решит "; break;
  }
  printf('Добро пожаловать, уважаем%s %s',$ending,$realname);
}elseif(mysql_num_rows($res)>1){
  die('Гы, база допустила двух пользователей с одинаковыми логинами и паролями');
}else{
  echo('пара логин/пароль неверна');
}
```

Comment: Не очень. Они простоваты, их легко проверить самому. Просто элементарно: `$_SESSION[]` - это массив. Можно просто подставить в него какой-нибудь ключ, какое-нибудь значение и проверить что получится. `print_r($_SESSION)` вам в помощь.

Comment: А вот если мне нужно вывести Имя  юнита как это сделать?

Comment: Влад, в твоей игре можно будет грабить корованы?

Comment: тогда в список запрашиваемых полей ввести еще одно - имя юнита:
$sql = 'select `realname`,`username`,`sex`,`unit_name`,`unit_sex`,`unit_race` from `users` where `username`='.$username.' and `password`='.md5($password);

Comment: @alienator, можно. ждите обновлений и вопросов: "Как грабить корованы на PHP+MySql"

Comment: @knes, я внутренне уже готов к таким вопросам

Comment: [Корованы][1]

  [1]:http://lurkmore.ru/Корованы

Comment: Ай да молодцы !!!

Comment: О-да))) Я хоть и чайник но не такой))))